# Question about the proof of the Cauchy Binet Formula

Tags: proof-verification, determinant

Let $A$ be a $k\times n$ matrix and $B$ be a $n\times k$ matrix.

> $\textbf{Goal:}$ I'm trying to show $\begin{equation}\det(AB)=\sum_{j_1,j_2, ...,j_k=1}^n b_{j_1,1}b_{j_2,2}...b_{j_k,k}\det(A(j_1, j_2, ..., j_k)) \end{equation}$ as shown in this proof for the [Cauchy Binet Formula](https://www.google.com/search?q=cauchy%20binet%20formula&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS815US815&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=-TCioA7xedMtsM%253A%252C6u0YpRwJ2440zM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTLxhv7fbxa_84-cCmmJPJ5c2kwUg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjpj6eJw6fiAhVHcq0KHeLPAGYQ9QEwAHoECAsQBg#imgrc=kwHO-qCW7pES_M:&vet=1).
>
> > Note: I was using a linear map for determinants which can be found here on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map), and $\hat{e}_j$ denotes a single column with all zero's except the $j^{th}$ row which is a one.
>
> $\textbf{Question:}$ Would the proof below work? I feel like I went wrong somewhere because I believe the last couple lines are wrong. Any help would be appreciated!

$\begin{align*}\det(AB)&=\det((AB)_1, (AB)_2, ..., (AB)_k) \text{ where } (AB)_i \text{denotes the } i^{th} \text{column of } AB\\
&=\det(\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j_1=1}^na_{i,j_1}b_{j_1,1}\cdot \hat{e}_i,\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j_2=1}^na_{i,j_2}b_{j_2,2}\cdot \hat{e}_i , ..., \sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j_k=1}^na_{i,j_k}b_{j_k,k}\cdot \hat{e}_i ) \\
&=\sum_{i_1,i_2, ..., i_k=1}^k\det(\sum_{j_1=1}^na_{i_1,j_1}b_{j_1,1}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_1},\sum_{j_2=1}^na_{i_2,j_2}b_{j_2,2}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_2} , ..., \sum_{j_k=1}^na_{i_k,j_k}b_{j_k,k}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_k} ) \\
&=\sum_{i_1,i_2, ..., i_k=1}^k\sum_{j_1,j_2, ...,j_k=1}^n\det(a_{i_1,j_1}b_{j_1,1}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_1},a_{i_2,j_2}b_{j_2,2}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_2} , ..., a_{i_k,j_k}b_{j_k,k}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_k} ) \\
&=\sum_{j_1,j_2, ...,j_k=1}^n\sum_{i_1,i_2, ..., i_k=1}^k\det(a_{i_1,j_1}b_{j_1,1}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_1},a_{i_2,j_2}b_{j_2,2}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_2} , ..., a_{i_k,j_k}b_{j_k,k}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_k} ) \\
&=\sum_{j_1,j_2, ...,j_k=1}^n b_{j_1,1}b_{j_2,2}...b_{j_k,k}\sum_{i_1,i_2, ..., i_k=1}^k\det(a_{i_1,j_1}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_1},a_{i_2,j_2}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_2} , ..., a_{i_k,j_k}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_k} ) \\
&=\sum_{j_1,j_2, ...,j_k=1}^n b_{j_1,1}b_{j_2,2}...b_{j_k,k}\det(A(j_1, j_2, ..., j_k)) \\
\end{align*}$

Comment: Why do you think the last lines are wrong?  They are correct.

Comment: So, then does $\det(A(j_1, j_2, ..., j_k)):=\sum_{i_1,i_2, ..., i_k=1}^k\det(a_{i_1,j_1}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_1},a_{i_2,j_2}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_2} , ..., a_{i_k,j_k}\cdot \hat{e}_{i_k} )$, or does it equal that for another reason? I felt that was a problem, because I did not think those terms were equal. Answering that would answer my question.

Comment: Yes.  Note that $a_{i_1,j_1}$ is $A(J)_{i_1,1}$, $a_{i_2,j_2}$ is $A(J)_{i_2,2}$, etc. so this reduces to the definition of determinant.

Comment: Ohhh! I just got it! Please feel free to put what you just wrote above to answer this question. It makes sense to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
A_{i_m,j_m}=A(J)_{i_m.m}\quad \text{for all }m=1,2,\dots,k
$$
since the $k\times k$ matrix $A(J)$ is constructed by picking $j_1,j_2,j_3,\dots$ columns of $A$ as the first, second, third, ... columns of $A(J)$.  So
$$
\det(a_{i_1,j_1}\cdot\hat e_{i_1},a_{i_2,j_2}\cdot\hat e_{i_2},\dots,a_{i_l,j_k}\cdot\hat e_{i_k})
=\det(A(J)_{i_1,1}\cdot\hat e_{i_1},A(J)_{i_2,2}\cdot\hat e_{i_2},\dots,A(J)_{i_k,k}\cdot\hat e_{i_k})
$$
and thus the sum over all $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k$ is $\det A(J)$ by definition.